# подключение коннектора mySQL 8.0 к code::blocks c++

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

Пытаюсь использовать коннектер MySQL и C++

среда : 
Windows 10

Code::Blocks 17.12

MySQL 8.0

MySQL Connector C++ 8.0

Вроде как все инклуды и либы подключил, но все равно не робит.

linker settings:

> -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient

код:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{



cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' » AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

}

    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

логи:

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++14 -O2 -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysql" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysqlx" -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc\cppconn" -c C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\lib64" -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14" -o bin\Release\SQLfinal_connect.exe obj\Release\main.o  -lmysqlpp -lmysqlclient mysqlpp mysqlclient nsl z m -s
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/warning.h:40:0,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:39,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/sqlstring.h:46:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/sqlstring.h:47:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/sqlstring.h:51:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:39:0,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/warning.h:46:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/variant.h:44:0,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:41,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:65:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:69:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:70:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4275)
>    ^
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:75:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:4:0:
>   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\jdbc/mysql_connection.h:37:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

Comment: `fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory` - Нужно ставить библиотеку "Boost smart_ptr".

Comment: это что-то определенное, если так направляете? Просто пробежался по гуглу, никак не могу найти где скачать, а где-либо внутри коннектора его нет. Нужно ли как-то подключать инклуды/либы самого mySQL или все через коннектор делается?

Comment: Про коннектор не знаю, но сделал бы вот что: качаете буст [отсюда](https://www.boost.org/users/download/), достаете из архива папку `boost/smart_ptr`, и добавляете ее в пути к инклудам.

Comment: да, и в правду, помогло, но возник ряд других ошибок, думаю они связаны с чем-то другим(повторное обьявление int32_t) думаю отдельным вопросом сделаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавлю ответ-решение, для формальности.

Скачивание и последующее извлечение из архива папки boost в папку include коннектора решило данную проблему, огромная благодарность пользователю HolyBlackCat.

Папку нужно всю переносить, а не только smart_ptr, так как после, компилятор начинает жаловаться на отсутствие других файлов из этой папки(Boost)

Ссылка https://www.boost.org/users/download/