# mySQL 8.0 и C++ IDE не собирается видеть коннектор

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks, mysqlconnector

Пытаюсь использовать коннектер MySQL и C++

среда:
Windows 10
Code::Blocks 17.12
MySQL 8.0
MySQL Connector C++ 8.0

Пытаюсь подружить MySQL и Code::Blocks c++

предыдущие вопросы и решенные проблемы

[подключение коннектора mySQL 8.0 к code::blocks c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1027744/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-mysql-8-0-%D0%BA-codeblocks-c)

[Конфликт обьявлений mySQL connector + C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1027752/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-mysql-connector-c)

и вот, теперь после всего этого, IDE не собирается видеть коннектор

Пытаюсь компилировать "рабочий" пример из интернета.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD ""
#define DATABASE "database"


#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
            char ch;
            clock_t begin,end;
            MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);

            try {
                           connect = my_sql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
                           if( !connect ) throw "EROR: mySQL server not created\n";
            }
            catch(const char * eror) { printf(eror); }

            mysql_query(connect,"insert into podmenki values(1,'G1EDAJCHSD1273648','RENAULT','DUSTER','P238CM')");
            begin = clock();

            MYSQL_RES * res_set; MYSQL_ROW row;
            mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM database");
            res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

            end = clock();
            printf("Execution time is %f sec\n",(double)(begin-end) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

            mysql_close(connect);
            scanf("%c",&ch);
            return 0;
}
```

Логи:

> In file included from C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/variant.h:44:0,
>                    from C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/connection.h:41,
>                    from C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:36,
>                    from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysql/jdbc.h:31,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:2:
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:65:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning (disable : 4290)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:69:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:70:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4275)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/exception.h:75:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysql/jdbc.h:31:0,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:2:
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:183:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:184:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:188:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:194:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:195:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h:201:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   In file included from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0\include\mysql/jdbc.h:32:0,
>                    from C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:2:
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_driver.h:61:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(push)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_driver.h:62:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(disable: 4251)
>    ^
>   C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/mysql_driver.h:66:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma warning(pop)
>    ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:27:17: error: 'MYSQL' was not declared in this scope
>                    MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
>                    ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:27:24: error: 'connect' was not declared in this scope
>                    MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
>                           ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:27:49: error: 'mysql_init' was not declared in this scope
>                    MYSQL *connect = mysql_init(NULL);
>                                                    ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:30:108: error: 'my_sql_real_connect' was not declared in this scope
>                                   connect = my_sql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
>                                                                                                               ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:35:117: error: 'mysql_query' was not declared in this scope
>                    mysql_query(connect,"insert into podmenki values(1,'G1EDAJCHSD1273648','RENAULT','DUSTER','P238CM')");
>                                                                                                                        ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:38:17: error: 'MYSQL_RES' was not declared in this scope
>                    MYSQL_RES * res_set; MYSQL_ROW row;
>                    ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:38:29: error: 'res_set' was not declared in this scope
>                    MYSQL_RES * res_set; MYSQL_ROW row;
>                                ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:38:38: error: 'MYSQL_ROW' was not declared in this scope
>                    MYSQL_RES * res_set; MYSQL_ROW row;
>                                         ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:40:53: error: 'mysql_store_result' was not declared in this scope
>                    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);
>                                                        ^
>   C:\c++\programs\SQLfinal_connect\main.cpp:45:36: error: 'mysql_close' was not declared in this scope
>                    mysql_close(connect);

[image: include'ы]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выглядит будто вы хидера не подключили

Comment: извиняюсь, отошел, сейчас приложу скрины

Comment: а,не правильно понял, вроде все, что нужно подключил, вы случаем не сталкивались с данной связкой? Все, что есть в рабочих примерах, и при этом не "брыкается" подключил

Comment: что-то я не пойму, а откуда вы этот код (в main) взяли?

Comment: Вы определитесь, что вы собираетесь делать. Вот вы пытаетесь использовать "MySQL Connector C++", а в коде кусок использует C API.

Comment: Для работы MySQL C++ нужно собрать MySQL C API. Плюсовая библиотека работает через Сшную библиотеку.

Comment: main() и все #define взяты с гайда по использованию коннектора, правда, да, устаревшей его версии, но ничего более "свежего" я не нашел... я бы обошелся одним полноценным, актуальным гайдом для версий 8.0 но таких не смог найти, возможно по своей вине..

Comment: MrBin, т.е. мне нужно просто все подключить как для С в проекте где уже все подключено под с++? Извиняюсь за косноязычность, но по другому сформулировать пока не могу

Comment: я имею ввиду, нужно ли будет как-то "связывать" сишную и с++ варианты библиотек?*

Comment: [Сборки для windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/), но на счёт Сшного API не уверен. Его тоже скорее всего придется подключать. Вам просто нужно подключить Сшную библиотеку, все также как и с С++. К сожалению, я не помню про связывания С++ библиотеки с С.

Comment: MrBin,VTT, вот папка мускула, все , что можно скачал(добавил скрин)

Comment: Ищите в директории сервера хедеры и библиотеки для C и подключайте также. И ещё, ответы определенным людям идут с префиксом '@<ник>'.